# Selector from button created in category calls released method

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access, objective-c-category

I have a category of a class that creates a button that initializes properly with the following options

```
[cancelButton addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelReconnect:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

then in the same category.m file I have the method

```
-(void)cancelReconnect{ NSLog(@"here!"); }
```

When the button is pressed in the viewcontroller that imports the class which imports the category I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS and it appears my method/class seems like it was released.

If I put the same cancelReconnect method in the viewcontroller where 'self' would be. It is the same result.

Is my addTarget correct? is my selector method being released? How to solve this?

note the toolBarItems array in my custom class' .h file is strong but I don't know if the button in the array is. Does the View Controller keep a strong pointer to the Class's category method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making a common mistake. Your actual method is named `cancelReconnect` but you tell the button that the selector is named `cancelReconnect:` (notice the colon).

Change your method to:

```
- (void)cancelReconnect:(UIButton *)button {
    NSLog(@"here!");
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I have misdiagnosed the problem. Still getting error and breakpoints don't reach function. Can this function be called from the category's .m file using self?

Comment: The `cancelReconnect:` method needs to be in whatever class `self` is when you call `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`. If `self` is the category then `cancelReconnect:` needs to be in the category.

Comment: ok cool, just to clarify.. the `[myViewController addCancelButton]` method is called the the viewcontroller.m but addCancelButton method where the `addTarget:action:forControlEvents` is is in the category. self if the category.m ya?

Comment: there is no console output.. just `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)`

Comment: `self` is an instance of whatever class the method is called for. If the call to `addTarget:` is in the `addCancelButton` method, then `self` is the view controller.